# how to use material-ui component

Tags: reactjs

I wanna fix this problems.
Here is my code:

```
class Cards extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            title1: '',
            image: '',
            rating: '',
            loaded: false,
            title3:"",
            title4:""
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const { title1, title, image, rating, title3, title4 } = this.props;
        this.setState({ title1: title1, title: title, image: image, title3:title3, title4:title4, rating: rating, loaded: true });
    }

    render() {

        const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
            title_color: {
                color: 'white'
            },
            root: {
                // colorPrimary: '#ffffff',
                maxWidth: 345,
                height: 425
            },
            media: {
                height: 320,
                paddingTop: '56.25%',
                position: "relative"
            },

            body2: {
                marginTop: -60,
                position: "absolute",
            },

            body1: {
                marginTop: 15
            }

        }));

        const classes = useStyles();

        return (
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardMedia
                    className={classes.media}
                    image={this.state.img}
                />
                <CardContent className={classes.body2}>
                    <Typography className={classes.title_color} variant="body2" component="p">
                        {this.state.title}
                    <br></br>
                    {this.state.title1}
                </Typography>
                    <Typography component="p">
                        {this.state.title3}
                    <br></br>
                   {this.state.title4}
                </Typography>
                    <div>
                        <Box component="fieldset" mb={3} borderColor="transparent">
                            <Rating name="read-only" value={this.state.rating} readOnly />
                        </Box>
                    </div>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

export default Cards
But when I run this, these issues appear.
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: Check [this issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15820)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hooks in a class component[(react docs)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html):

> You can’t use Hooks inside a class component, but you can definitely mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single tree. Whether a component is a class or a function that uses Hooks is an implementation detail of that component. In the longer term, we expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components.

Try to write it as a functional component:

```
const Card = () => {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            title1: '',
            image: '',
            rating: '',
            loaded: false,
            title3:"",
            title4:""
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const { title1, title, image, rating, title3, title4 } = this.props;
        this.setState({ title1: title1, title: title, image: image, title3:title3, title4:title4, rating: rating, loaded: true });
    }

    render() {

        const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
            title_color: {
                color: 'white'
            },
            root: {
                // colorPrimary: '#ffffff',
                maxWidth: 345,
                height: 425
            },
            media: {
                height: 320,
                paddingTop: '56.25%',
                position: "relative"
            },

            body2: {
                marginTop: -60,
                position: "absolute",
            },

            body1: {
                marginTop: 15
            }

        }));

        const classes = useStyles();
        return (
            <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardMedia
                    className={classes.media}
                    image={this.state.img}
                />
                <CardContent className={classes.body2}>
                    <Typography className={classes.title_color} variant="body2" component="p">
                        {this.state.title}
                    <br></br>
                    {this.state.title1}
                </Typography>
                    <Typography component="p">
                        {this.state.title3}
                    <br></br>
                   {this.state.title4}
                </Typography>
                    <div>
                        <Box component="fieldset" mb={3} borderColor="transparent">
                            <Rating name="read-only" value={this.state.rating} readOnly />
                        </Box>
                    </div>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

export default Card;
```